# How do I use BigQuery Mate's parameters button

Tags: google-bigquery

I don't know how to use BigQuery Mate's parameters button. Could someone explain it with simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was introduced in BigQuery Mate relatively long before BigQuery introduced parameters (Oct. 2015 vs. Dec. 2016)

How to use this feature:
Within the text of your query - anything that has this pattern `<var_parametername>` is considered as parameter. So when you click on Parameters Button - Mate collects all such parameters and gives you ability to set their values. Then you can Run the query. Again  - this was introduced far before BigQuery supported real parameters and was more to support query templates - when you can save some commonly used query and then easily change some parameters (parts of the query) for ad-hoc runs

As parameters are still not supported in Native BigQuery UI - I would expect this can still be useful for some of us